# I am getting a SQL error when trying to update a form in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

```
<?php
$con3=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
     {
     echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
     }
      //$result = mysqli_query($con3,"SELECT * FROM servers");

     $updateln = $_POST ['LoggedIn'];
     $updateloc = $_POST ['Location'];
     $updateos = $_POST ['OperatingSystem'];
     $updatesn = $_POST ['ServerName'];

$updatesql="UPDATE servers SET LoggedIn='$updateln', Location='$updateloc'"
    . " OperatingSystem = '$updateos' WHERE ServerName = '$updatesn'";

if (!mysqli_query($con3,$updatesql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con3));
}
echo "Record Updated";
```

I am fairly new to PHP and SQL so I am not really sure what is wrong with the UPDATE sql.
This is the error I am getting

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OperatingSystem = 'ht' WHERE ServerName = 'hr'' at line 1

I have tried other stackoverflow questions and although some people have had problems with this before I can't really see where my code has gone wrong.

Comment: It looks like your missing a comma between the Location="..." and OperatingSystem="..."

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be missing a comma. Replace this:

```
"UPDATE servers SET LoggedIn='$updateln', Location='$updateloc'"
```

With this:

```
"UPDATE servers SET LoggedIn='$updateln', Location='$updateloc',"
```

Comment: Wow... that is frustrating. Thank you for your help. I will correct your answer when the 10 minute waiting period is up